# Replace files recursively in unix or linux through shell script

Tags: macos, zsh

I have more than 600 folder which contains action.js in various places. need to replace all through the script. Using Z shell in mac. With the below code, I am able to delete all action.js but need to replace another action.js in the same location.

```
find . -name "user.js" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    cp test.sh "$file"
    rm -rf  "$file"
    echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do  
    rm -rf  "$file"
    cp test.sh "$file"
    echo "$file"
done
```

You have to copy the new file after deleting